# Using .closest() with a button on click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a website with multiple forms on one page, and I'm trying to figure out how to use closest() to reference a drop down that's close to my submit button. Here's my jquery:

```
    var subcategory = $().closest('.subcategoryDropdown option:selected').val();
```

In the parentheses before .closest it needs to reference my button which doesn't have an id I could use (since there's multiple buttons that will be the same) so it needs to be something like an event trigger, but I'm really not sure how to do this. Here's my html:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria.Count; i++)
    {
<form id="@String.Format("form{0}", Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria[i].PartNumber)" action="">
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PartOverrideModel.Manufacturer)
<div>
    <div class="leftSide">
        <div class="mappingSubtitle">@Resources.EzpConsole.Current_Mapping<span class="partNumber">@Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria[i].PartNumber</span></div>
        <div>
            <div class="text">@Resources.EzpConsole.Current_Category</div>
            <div class="modelText">@Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria[i].CategoryKey</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="text">@Resources.EzpConsole.Current_Subcategory</div>
            <div class="modelText">@Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria[i].SubCategoryKey</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide">
        <div class="mappingSubtitle">@Resources.EzpConsole.New_Mappings@Model.PartOverrideModel.PartCriteria[i].PartNumber</div>
        <div>
            <div class="rightText">@Resources.EzpConsole.New_Category</div>
            <div class="mappingDropdowns">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartOverrideModel.SelectedCategory, Html.CreateCategorySelectList(Model.AllCategoryDetails, true, null), new { @class = "dropDown categoryDropdown", onchange = "javascript:ezpConsole.partOverride.showSubcategoryDropdown();" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="rightText">@Resources.EzpConsole.New_Subcategory</div>
            <span class="mappingDropdowns" id="subcategoryDropdownPlaceholder">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartOverrideModel.SelectedCategory, Html.CreateCategorySelectList(Model.AllCategoryDetails, true, null), new { @class = "dropDown", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </span>
            <div class="lowerButton">
                <a class="standardWhiteButton"  onclick="javascript:ezpConsole.partOverride.updateParts();"
                    href="javascript:void();">@Resources.EzpConsole.Submit</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
}
```

This also uses a partial view for a second dropdown that is populated based on the selection the user makes on the first drop down.

```
    <div>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartOverrideModel.SelectedCategory, Html.CreateCategorySelectList(Model.AllCategoryDetails, false, (int)ViewBag.CategoryID), new { @class = "dropDown subcategoryDropdown"})
```

Comment: 1: Is that line inside a click handler for the button you want to reference in the `$()`? 2: We need to see your html.

Comment: try $(this).closest('.subcategoryDropdown option:selected').val();

Comment: Sorry Jason, here's my html. It's inside a function that's called from the view. Before that is just some basic validation.

Comment: @MaxFrazier where is .subcategoryDropdown ??

Comment: That's a class in my view on the form.

Comment: we need to see the button and that dropdown in html.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Comment: @MaxFrazier jQuery traversal functions work by going up, down, or across nodes. We need to see how the button and dropdown relate to each other. We need to see both of them in the same snippet.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm still learning this.

Comment: The `$(selector).closest(selector2)` function finds the nearest parent (starting with the element in `selector`). It doesn't find siblings. Have you tried finding the nearest parent element of the button and then doing a `.find('.subcategoryDropdown option:selected')`? For example, `$(this).closest('selector of parent element').find('.subcategoryDropdown option:selected').val()`. In other words, you need to traverse back to the parent and down its children to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    var subcategory = $(this).closest('form').find('.subcategoryDropdown option:selected').val();
    // do something
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/EUFxC/